# Restart the whole device from Android

Tags: android, timer, restart

Is there any way to restart a device per code from within android. I can highly customize all software on the device (tablet). As Backgroundinfo: I want a timer that restarts the device after a defined count if he did not get reseted.

***Edit:***

If there there is no Buildin-Way is it possible to do this anyway?

Comment: I *hate* software that does this type of thing... what happens if the user is in the middle of sending an e-mail, or a phone call?

Comment: Don't assume the user is using a personal device: it may be perfectly valid given specific use cases to force a reset, and you have no way of knowing if the actual implementation will prompt the user before resetting.

Comment: @forsvarir as @Femi suggest it is a special usecase and no public software you can download.

Comment: Whilst I can see some occasions where it might be useful, I still hate it as a user :)  RE: You quesion, are you confined to using an official android release, or is using one of the open source / modded versions an option (this may allow you more access)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general Google dont allow third party apps to Reboot device below are few link might be helpful

http://groups.google.com/group/android-platform/browse_thread/thread/daf7c685e020d296

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/5a97467ef5b4bf47/a1fe9379d4f5e30f?pli=1

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible from within an app, I believe.

The intent for rebooting the device (ACTION_REBOOT, if I recall, but I'm happy to be corrected!) can only be called from the system itself, not from any software residing on it.

(See the Android reference docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_REBOOT).)